# Google Play Game Services iOS GPGManager validOrientationFlags deprecated. Replaced with?

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation, google-play-services, google-play-games

I am developing an iOS landscape game in iOS 8, and am using the latest GooglePlayGames SDK v3.1.

On iOS 7, the Welcome Back Toast message is properly rotated, but in iOS 8, the Toast message is still stuck in portrait mode.

I understand that in the new SDK, the GPGManager validOrientationFlags is deprecated.

Any ideas on how to rotate the Toast Message in iOS 8 to landscape? Much appreciated.